# I have multiple tables, that share column names however they have different data

Tags: sql, vba

I'm having an issue when using VBA to pull an SQL query from Oracle where I have multiple tables that share the same name, however hey contain different data. When I put the Oracle query directly into excel, the columns I want come out as "COLUMN_NAME","COLUMN_NAME_1", "COLUMN_NAME_2", not literally "column", but you get the drift. I'm trying to set them into fields in Excel VBA, however this is causing runtime errors.

```
ws = worksheet
rs = recordsheet
i = rows

ws.Cells(i, ColumnNeed).value = rs.("COLUMN_NAME")
ws.Cells(i, ColumnNeed1).value = rs.("COLUMN_NAME_1")
```

Comment: what is the error message, it could help to diagnosis your problem for others.

Answer (score 1):

Just use *fully qualified* field names and *table aliases* in you oracle query ! You will avoid those issues and have a more readable SQL statement.

```
SELECT p.someField personField, o.someField orderField  
FROM people p  
INNER JOIN orders o ON p.Id = o.buyerId
```